# What is the MonoDroid equivalent for this Android Code

Tags: android, xamarin.android

How do I convert the following to Mono for Android code?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, countries);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I can't find a ".setAdapter"

Thanks,

Comment: Gets and Sets as a rule of thumb are usually just direct properties in MonoDroid. Being a C# dev who occasionally writes java. I think that properties are easier to read but, that may be just a personal pref.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
textView.Adapter = adapter;
```

work?

Comment: @Fritz: Accept this answer if it helps you sold problem :)